# What am I doing wrong with this mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a table for a blog and I am attempting to store 2 pictures in it so I resorted to storing it with a LONGBLOB (even though I know that everyone recommends storing it to the filesystem and then adding a link to it in the database but the thing is that there will be only one user and that will be me so there is no reason to overcomplicate it because this will not be a large amount of data or big pictures). Here is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE posts{
id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
picOne LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
picTwo LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The error I get is

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'MAX) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (id) )' at line 5

I think that I am using the word MAX wrong or maybe there is something wrong with my whole data type or perhaps there is a better approach to this.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: First error is you are using `{` as in `CREATE TABLE posts {` instead of `(`

Comment: Sorry, I am just used to writing it that way. In my SQL I actually use () for it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. These should be the same () when creating a new table.

> 'CREATE TABLE posts{'
>
> );

```
   CREATE TABLE posts(
  id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  picOne LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
  picTwo LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL
  );
```

Comment: I simply wrote a typo on the question, sorry. In my actual SQL I used ()

Comment: CREATE TABLE posts{
id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
picOne LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
picTwo LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL
);'

Comment: It still gives me the same error, no matter how I try it.
It says that there is a problem with my MAX

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Does it work if you replace 'MAX' with a arbitrary integer?

Comment: I am running version 5.7.14.
And it seems that it is not working when I use an arbitrary integer.

Answer (score 0):

Its the inappropriate curly brace `{` that you are using. Use the following query -

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
picOne LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
picTwo LONGBLOB(MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Perhaps just a typo.

Comment: I simply did a typo on the question, but when I try it with normal () it doesn't work.

Comment: There could be another issue though the create table statement looks fine here. What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced VARCHAR(MAX) to TEXT and LONGBLOB(MAX) to LONGBLOB. You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  picOne LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  picTwo LONGBLOB NOT NULL
  );
```

Comment: The '10' in parentheses following BIGINT is almost meaningless - and surely doesn't mean whatever you think it does!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was change the VARCHAR value to something really high like VARCHAR(10000) and then leave the LONGBLOB to stand on its own and it worked perfectly. Here is what the code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
picOne LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
picTwo LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```